# Sort DateTime in telerik

Tags: c#, datetime, gridview, time, telerik-grid

I have a grid with a column for time. 
If i convert the time to- ToShortTimeString() then the sorting on telerik grid doesn't work correctly. it doesn't consider the time but considers it as a String.

How can i sort the Time?

eg-

[Code]

DateTime DepartureTime {get; set;}

if time is 04/02/2014 5:30:00 PM.
           04/03/2014 7:00 AM

I only want to display time(5:30 PM or 7:00 AM) part in column.. And it should sort in ascending as

7:00 AM
5:30 PM

Answer (score 0):

Do not pre-convert the value to ToShortTimeString() string and bind it.
Bind it as DepartureTime, with SortExpression as DepartureTime and Data Type as DateTime.

Use the FormatString attribute of the Grid View Rows to display the value you need.
You can also use partial properties, methods etc. to render the string.

```
<telerik:GridDateTimeColumn DataField="DepartureTime" DataType="System.DateTime" 
    DataFormatString="{0:hh:mm tt}" 
    HeaderText="DepartureTime" SortExpression="DepartureTime" UniqueName="DepartureTime"> 
</telerik:GridDateTimeColumn>
```

OR

```
<telerik:GridDateTimeColumn DataField="DepartureTime" DataType="System.DateTime" 
    DataFormatString="{0:t}" 
    HeaderText="DepartureTime" SortExpression="DepartureTime" UniqueName="DepartureTime"> 
</telerik:GridDateTimeColumn>
```